# How can you programatically add a class variable to a class in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

How can you programatically add a class variable to a class in Pharo? It should be in the class builder, that's where you can add instance variables to a class. But I don't see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MyClass addClassVarNamed: 'MyClassVariable'
```